# How to trigger jenkins Job on code pushed to development server?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I have development code repository at bitbucket and another test script code repository at bitbucket. Now I have setup a Jenkins job by linking test code repository. Is there any way to trigger jenkins job automatically on change in development repository ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the [BitBucket Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin) to your Jenkins instance. It will allow you to configure a webhook in BitBucket that will then trigger any Jenkins job listening for that webhook. The plugin's page has a detailed breakdown, but the basics are;

1. In your repo in BitBucket, [create a new Webhook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html) using your Jenkins' url. I believe the url is generally `http://[your jenkins url]/bitbucket-hook/`
2. Make the trigger a repo push.
3. In your Jenkins job, check the box "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" under the Build Triggers section.

Now any time you commit to the repo you created the Webhook on, that Jenkins job will be run.

You can also limit what branches trigger commits by parameterizing your Jenkins build to ignore certain branches / keywords / etc if that's something you need for your specific project.

Comment: Yes that's true, but I think that is possible when your development code and test code are in same repository. In my case we have two different repository for different codes (in one my application code is present and from another jenkins is pulling my test code ).

Comment: @TapasMahato Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but this setup works even with different repos. We do this in both our product and develop repos and have customized the triggers to ignore all but specific branches to cut down on noise.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for reaching me out. Currently I am busy with another task. I would try again as per your directions and let you update on same. May be I would need your assistance at that time. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

[Builds by source changes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project)

You can have Jenkins poll your Revision Control System for changes. You can specify how often Jenkins polls your revision control system using the same syntax as crontab on Unix/Linux. However, if your polling period is shorter than it takes to poll your revision control system, you may end up with multiple builds for each change. You should either adjust your polling period to be longer than the amount of time it takes to poll your revision control system, or use a post-commit trigger. You can examine the Polling Log for each build to see how long it took to poll your system.

Alternatively, instead of polling on a fixed interval, you can use a URL trigger (described above), but with /polling instead of /build at the end of the URL. This makes Jenkins poll the SCM for changes rather than building immediately. This prevents Jenkins from running a build with no relevant changes for commits affecting modules or branches that are unrelated to the job. When using /polling the job must be configured for polling, but the schedule can be empty.